# Python: monkey patch a function used by classes in the same module

Tags: python, python-module, monkeypatching

I want to modify a function (not a method) in a module, such that the classes within the same module that use that function behave differently.

For the sake of simplicity assume I have a file called `_module.py` and a file `__init__.py` that sit in a directory called `my_library`.

```py
# file _module.py
def _do_something():
    print('hello')

class foo():
    def bar(self):
        _do_something()
```

```py
# file __init__.py
from ._module import foo
```

I have tried monkey patching the function `_do_something` like this

```py
import my_library
my_library._do_something = lambda: print('goodbye')
a = my_library.foo()
a.bar()
```

but it still outputs `hello`. I also have tried the following

```py
from my_library import foo, _do_something
_do_something = lambda: print('goodbye')
a = foo()
a.bar()
```

but it throws a `cannot import name '_do_something' from 'my_library'` error.

How can I modify `_do_something` such that the change is reflected when I call `foo.bar`?

PS: Actually I want to change the function `_estimate_gaussian_parameters` used by `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` and both are located in the same file. But I don't think this is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should patch the function of *`_module`* and not the one imported in `my_library`:

```
import my_library
my_library._module._do_something = lambda: print('goodbye')
a = my_library.foo()
a.bar()
```

Also I recommend using `unittest.mock` (see [doc for patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)):

```
import my_library
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch.object(my_library._module, '_do_something', lambda: print('goodbye')):
    a = my_library.foo()
    a.bar()
```

Comment: Verey thorough answear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to modify the function `_do_something`, you must make sure that you modify the function directly in the exact module it is located in.

The issue with your attempt is that you're trying to modify the function in the imported module `my_library`, but the method `foo.bar` is referencing the original function `_do_something` from `_module.py`.

```py
import my_library

# Monkey patch the function in the module where its from
my_library._module._do_something = lambda: print('goodbye')

a = my_library.foo()
a.bar() #'goodbye'
```

Notice how in the code above we're accessing the function within _module.py directly. This is the key!

Comment: Thank yiu this was helpful.